# Como usar o bytes do BitConverter.ToDouble

Tags: c#, pic

Tenho uma interface que envia para um microcontrolador um valor de referência. Preciso enviar os valores em bytes pois esses valores vão ficar gravados na memória do microcontrolador. Na interface, em C# estou usando por exemplo:

```
double referencia = 125.6589;
byte[] byteArray = BitConverter.GetBytes(referencia);
```

Então em envio essa sequencia de bytes "byteArray". Para o microcontrolador.

Mas como eu posso usar essa sequencia de bytes para reconstruir esse valor de referência, que vou precisar usar no microcontrolador?

No microcontrolador preciso encontrar um float:

```
float referencia = 125.6589;
```

Usando aquela sequencia de bytes para obter esse valor. Qual operação matemática que posso usar para obter esse valor.

Obs. O microcontrolador é um PIC, programado em C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O `BitConverter` usa o formato IEEE-754 para representar os valores em ponto flutuante, o que é o formato usado pelos compiladores de C para representar os valores `double` (8 bytes) ou `float` (4 bytes). Com isso, você pode converter os bytes que você recebe do `BitConverter.GetBytes` usando um `cast` para o tipo desejado. Por exemplo, o seu `byteArray` para o número que você tem equivale aos seguintes bytes:

```
67,D5,E7,6A,2B,6A,5F,40
```

para ver como cheguei nesses bytes, basta imprimir o valor:

```
double referencia = 125.6589;
byte[] byteArray = BitConverter.GetBytes(referencia);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", byteArray.Select(b => string.Format("{0:X2}", b))));
```

Do lado do C, você precisa de alguma forma receber no seu controlador os bytes gerados pelo `BitConverter`, e fazer um cast para o tipo correspondente. Note que se você tem 8 bytes de entrada, você não pode usar o tipo `float` em C (que tem 4 bytes), deve usar `double`.

```
char bytes[8];
bytes[0] = 0x67;
bytes[1] = 0xD5;
bytes[2] = 0xE7;
bytes[3] = 0x6A;
bytes[4] = 0x2B;
bytes[5] = 0x6A;
bytes[6] = 0x5F;
bytes[7] = 0x40;
double *d = (double *)bytes;
double referencia = *d;
printf("Valor: %lf\n", referencia);
```

Note que é possível que o controlador tenha uma *endianness* diferente do computador onde a referência foi gerada (big vs. little endian), então talvez você tenha que inverter a ordem dos bytes. Quando você fizer um teste vai saber rapidamente se isso é o caso ou não.